# How to compress video in AWS s3 storage?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am very new to AWS, we are just using s3 bucket to save video data generated from our web application backend.

We have a check in backend, if video size from front end in mora than 65mb it wont send to aws s3.

Due to new devices coming in the market and because of high resolution the size of the video is increasing.

Is there any way in aws s3, before saving or after saving to s3 bucket, compress it automatically.

I did some research there is MediaConvert service where we can do manually compression.

But i need as soon as we save from our application it should be compressed and save in s3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS S3 will not compress the files for storage. It stores what you provide. If you want S3 to store compressed videos, you need to compress the videos yourself and upload them to S3 that way.

The objects you upload need to be compressed before they're uploaded.

Comment: Thank you for clear cut answer. It help me not to research more on aws side